# R - Export High Quality Plots

Tags: r, export

This has been asked many different ways, but I have not found a solution that works entirely well for me.

This is a screenshot of one of my UMAPs in R Project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi88R.png)

I found an export to PDF function here, and this is the code:

```
  pdf(file = paste(strPlotDirectory, strPlotName, sep=''))
  
  dev.set(which = 2)
  dev.copy(which = 4)
  dev.off()
```

And this is what the PDF looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlnJm.png)

Looks at those SAUSAGE dots.  I have no preference if the plots are exported as PDF, png, TIFF.  I have tried them all.  The PDFs are the best I can make them look.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

The code to generate the UMAPs is from the CATALYST package, they have a few different plot functions - https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/CATALYST.html.  Happy to include that code if deemed relevant.

Thanks all.

Comment: It looks like your PDF device is much smaller than your other image. Try setting a larger width= and height= in the `pdf()` call.

Comment: have you tried with svg format?

Comment: Generally `dev.copy()` produces a worse result than plotting directly to the target device.  You need something like `pdf(file = paste(strPlotDirectory, strPlotName, sep='')); [code to do plotting]; dev.off()`.

Comment: When exporting to a PDF or image, you can adjust the `pointsize` of the plot. If you reduce the point size, all points, labels, and axes get smaller and finer while the general width and height of the image remain the same. (If you reduce it too far, you may need to increase the `axis.cex` to get legible axes.)